# Java Certificates, Eclipse and Maven: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cacerts

The project when "clean install" search for "eiUtil jar" at local .m2 and if not exist.

It tries to search remote artifactory and gives following:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for Gullaintegrator:eiutil:jar:2.15-SNAPSHOT: 
   Could not transfer artifact Gullaintegrator:eiutil:pom:2.15-SNAPSHOT from/to Gullaintegrator-snapshots 
   (https://artifactory.Gullaintegrator.cosng.net/libs-snapshot): 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
      unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The solution suggested is to go to https://artifactory.gullaintegrator.cosng.net/ and download certificate on Chrome and install it in Java certificates (lib\security\cacerts). It worked for one system somehow.

Is this an only solution for the same?
What is problem actually?
and why such exercise is required? Is there temporary and quick fix to this in eclipse?

Comment: Looks like an [artifactory known issue](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/)

Comment: The given url is not reachable... missing DNS entry looks very suspicious...

Answer (score 2):

The PKIX error message means that the Java VM doesn't trust the server's certificate.

You should download the certificate of the server ( or the certificate of the certification authority that issued it) and add it to the cacerts keystore of the java VM that you are using to run Maven.

To add the certificate you can use the command line utility keytool.

Answer (score 2):

By default Eclipse uses its embedded openjdk jre situated in its plugins folder. This same jre is used by Eclipse Maven plugin (m2e) to solve pom.xml dependencies regardless of what java version was set in the pom.xml or installed JRE's configured in the Eclipse preferences. So you will need to import the certificate of the repositor you are using, into this embedded jre truststore under:
**eclipse_installation/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk[...]/jre/lib/security/cacerts**.

For example Eclipse 2021.3, has embedded openjdk jre v.15, so the cacerts file is situated here:

*/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955/jre/lib/security/cacerts*

In your case it might be that on one system Eclipse uses the installed jre/jdk (where the certtificare was imported) and on another system uses its embedded openjdk jre (where the certificate was not imported).

To find out what JVM is used by Eclipse look into eclipse.ini file, in case of Eclipse 2021.3 we will find:

```
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955/jre/bin
```